How to modify the code for the display of the lenticular effect in the Html
I am Derby. I am new in this community. I would need the help to modify the code for the display of the lenticular effect in the Html as the result of the demonstration on the website lenticular effect (https://codepen.io/FallenHoot/pen/bGGQOLq). The source code is from the project entitled "lenticular effect" (https://codepen.io/FallenHoot/pen/bGGQOLq). I tried to combine the codes from the html, CSS and JavaScript into the html under one simple file to display the lenticular effect in the html, but I cannot perform the same result as the demonstration on the website lenticular effect (https://codepen.io/FallenHoot/pen/bGGQOLq). Attached is the source code. I wish the source code and the link from one old project would help you solve the problem and provide the solutions based on your specialty. Thank you.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @-webkit-keyframes move {
      from {
        stop-opacity: 1;
      }
      to {
        stop-opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes move {
      from {
        stop-opacity: 1;
      }
      to {
        stop-opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .app {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .app .img {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }
    
    .app svg {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Test lenticular effect</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://cf.ltkcdn.net/family/images/orig/200821-2121x1414-family.jpg')" alt="" />
  </div>

  <script>
    class Lenticular2 {
      constructor(container, params) {
        this.container = container;
        // this.params = {...params};

        this.render();
      }

      render() {
        const generateSvg = () => {
          return `
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1">
      <defs>
          <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientTransform="rotate(0)">
            <stop offset="0%"    style="  stop-color:white;" stop-opacity:1 />
            <stop offset="100%"; style="  stop-color:white;" stop-opacity:0 />
          </linearGradient>

            <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
            </mask>

      </defs>
        <image mask="url(#mask)" width="100%" height="100%" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="https://www.richscatering.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/family_friendly.jpg" />
    </svg>
    `;
        };
        this.container.append(generateSvg());
        this.mousemove();
      }

      mousemove() {
        // animate gradient x2
        $(".app").on("mousemove", e => {
          let width = this.container.find("svg").innerWidth();

          const offset = [0, 100];
          const opacity = [1, 0];

          $("#gradient").attr("x2", e.pageX / width * 200 + "%");

          $("#gradient stop").each((i, el) => {
            $(el).attr(
              "offset",
              parseFloat(offset[i]) + e.pageX / width * 100 + "%"
            );

            if (i === 0) {
              $(el).attr("stop-opacity", opacity[i] - e.pageX / width);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }

    let lenticular2 = new Lenticular2($(".app"));
  </script>

</body>

</html>



